# Quadratic form for specific formula as matrix reprezentation

Tags: functions, matrix

So I have problem for specific formula to create [Quadratic_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) form from $$y = 3 + x_1 - 2 x_4 + 2 x_3 x_4 + x_2 (-x_3 + x_4) $$ as matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
    0  & -1/2 & 0 & 1 \\
0  & 1/2 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
We have in Mathematica special function for this?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the coefficients and the values in the matrix, so I can't help.  The reference doesn't explain the form either.

Comment: @mikado of course, I fixed this issue. The representation of quadratic form as matrix, more is here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form

Comment: Suggest you look at `CoefficientArray`

Comment: Quoting the first line from the linked page, "In mathematics, a quadratic form is a polynomial with terms all of degree two." The example has terms not of degree two. So it needs to be made clear what exactly is wanted.

Comment: Is this a description of what you want?  You want to determine a symmetric matrix $A$ such that if $x=(1,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, then $x^T A x = 3 + x_1 - 2 x_4 + 2 x_3 x_4 + x_2 (-x_3 + x_4)$

Comment: Have a look at `SolveAlways`.

Comment: @yarchik has provided you with the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to determine a symmetric matrix $A$ such that if $x=(1,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and

$$x^T A x = 3 + x_1 - 2 x_4 + 2 x_3 x_4 + x_2 (-x_3 + x_4)$$

then the following (based on the comment by @yarchik) should do that:

```
(* Create a symbolic symmetric matrix *)
A = Table[a[Min[i, j], Max[i, j]], {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 4}];

(* Quadratic form *)
y = 3 + x1 - 2 x4 + 2 x3 x4 + x2 (-x3 + x4)

(* Solve for the values of the symmetric matrix *)
x = {1, x1, x2, x3, x4};
(A = A /. SolveAlways[x.A.x == y, {x1, x2, x3, x4}][[1]]) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 3 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

As a check...

```
x.A.x // Simplify
(* 3 + x1 - 2 x4 + 2 x3 x4 + x2 (-x3 + x4) *)
```